# what formula do I need to search and insert text from one cell into another(not all of the text), as long as the information is the most recent?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As I'm new to excel functions and formulas, what formula do I need to search and insert text from one cell into another(not all of the text)as long as the information is the most recent?

i.e

The table to be inserted into has 4 horizontal rows to compare it to(for which is the newest), and whatever the most recent/new(based off date input in table B) input there is, Then it will take the relevant info and place it into Table A, leaving the other 3 rows blank.

Now in this case to be more specific:

- The 4 "rows" are names of people
- The information it is looking for is "price"
- The end result should have the price showing in one row only

In table B, the 4 rows of names are also present and in the cell There will be information referring to:

- (price:*) (quantity:*) (when bought: */*/*) (when replaced: */*/*)

If feasible, I was also going to add a fifth row named "shoestring" to add into cells quantity types like ML or KG etc, and any other information that may be handy.

ive been trying to look at a combination of formulas like "=IF(OR"
"=IFS" "=IF(Countif" ....etc

though im too "green" at using formulas in excel to know to how layer formulas and use them efficiently &/or know what ones work best for this situation.

The one I have in my example I know wont work that well , but should at least give an idea of roughly what I want.
thanks heaps.

Example of if it worked:
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CFu8.png)

Example of how it looks:
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKHNj.png)

Example 2:
[and here's a link of said example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QcysHmbMqZh6Rip7WP8pTkEzr0PpzWGu5gXpEOAUqSE/edit?usp=sharing)

Using he image example, housemate 2 has the newest /most recent product (2023) , and so above in the green table, his price should show, and nothing else. the other 3 have older products and as such would be blank.

the "price" example in the image is "2", so in the above green table, housemate 2's "price" column will have "2"

To do this I need a few things to happen. lets use housemate 2 again as another example.

1. I want Table A. (*top green table*) to show the category asked for. but only by the most recent purchase.
2. This means I want Table A. to have a formula/code that recognises the date of its respective counterpart in Table B.(in this example, housemate 2 has "*1/2/2023*" In table B.)
3. I then want Table A. to compare the other 3 housemates purchase dates in Table B.
4. By comparing the dates in Table B. I want it to continue with the formula in Table A. ONLY IF , it is the most recent purchase ( In this example, **housemate 2** has the **most recent purchase**. And as such, will continue the formula. housemates 1,2 & 3 will now show blank)
5. Now I want Table A. to show the Specified category above. ( the category in this image example is "*price*" )
6. To do this I want a search/if/or function [or whatever works best] to Get the categories data to be by itself in Table A. ( in this image example , housemate 2's data in Table B. is '*(price:**4**) (quantity:) (when bought: //) (when replaced: 1/2/2023)*' .... Here it should Isolate the data in '*(price:**4**)*' and thus in Table A. show "**4**" )

Comment: I am not following. Can you add a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what your desired output is?

Comment: I've edited and tried to make it clearer! hopefully that is a bit easier to understand.

Comment: have you considered using support columns to show the date first?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have a string of characters in a range of cells that each contain a date and price, and are looking to display the price of only the furthest date? Try the below. It will only work if the syntax for each cell is the same (i.e. there are always parenthesis around the price, the last bit of information is the date, etc.).

First, create and adjacent helper column that extracts the dates and drag down something like this formula:
`=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(P7, LEN(P7)-FIND("Replaced:", P7)-8))`

Next, test if the date is the largest in the range and if so, extract the price. Try something like:

```
=IF(Q1=MAX($Q$1:$Q$4),
MID(P7, FIND("Price: ", P7)+7,
FIND(")", P7)-FIND("Price: ", P7)-7),
"")
```

For example:

[image]